# Input text in graphics in C programming

Tags: c, turbo-c

I am making a project in C. Its simple, just a Hangman Game.

Got the logic already cause I've done that only in console.

Now, I'm trying to do it in C again with GRAPHICS. I am using Turbo C.

I've read some of the functions of `graphics.h`: so far I've seen `outtext()` / `outtextxy()` something like that. It can print a string.

Can you input a char or string in graphics? Searched a lot but seen nothing. 
Seen only drawing shapes examples.

How do you input characters, integers etc. in the graphics mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From memory, while you *can* use regular stdio functions `printf`, `scanf`, and `gets`, the graphics driver will paint them over your screen onto a "virtual cursor" position and scroll the screen when it reaches the bottom. You can use the nonstandard `conio.h` functions such as `gotoxy` and attempt to position the cursor, but it's still a mediocre way of inputting text, messing up the graphics stuff. You also cannot use the fancy fonts!

So use `getch` to read characters without showing them; update a string buffer (manually handling special keys such as <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and <kbd>Return</kbd>), and draw that on the screen using a font of your choice.

A short sample snippet of code to get you started:

```
#define MAX_INPUT_LEN 80

char inputbuf[MAX_INPUT_LEN];
int input_pos = 0;
```

then, in your main loop

```
int the_end = 0;
do
{
   outtextxy (0,0, inputbuf);
   c = getch();
   switch (c)
   {
        case 8: /* backspace */
          if (input_pos)
          {
             input_pos--;
             inputbuf[input_pos] = 0;
          }
          break;
        case 13: /* return */
          the_end = 1;
          break;
        case 27: /* Escape = Abort */
          inputbuf[0] = 0;
          the_end = 1;
          break;
        default:
          if (input_pos < MAX_INPUT_LEN-1 && c >= ' ' && c <= '~')
          {
             inputbuf[input_pos] = c;
             input_pos++;
             inputbuf[input_pos] = 0;
          }
   }
} while (!the_end);
```

Before you draw the text, make sure to erase the previous line! I left that out because it's been *too* long ago I used Turbo-C.

Answer (score 0):

For taking input from used.. you can use scanf function similar to how we take input in any non-graphics c program.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using normal scanf function. And by using sprintf copy a integer/whatever variable into a string. Now you can use outtextxy to set the string in specified location using x,y axis. Check geeksforgeeks to learn sprintf syntax.

I know it is too late. Hope it helps someone else.!